# Insanely basic UITableView & saving/loading data inquiry

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uikit

Very sorry for the basic question but I've seen this implemented in so many (disparate) ways that I'm not certain what the accepted method might be.

All I want is an app that records a list of words. The words should be displayed in a UITableView. The user can add/delete words. The words should be stored in a local file (plist, xml, etc. - the on-disk format really doesn't matter to me).

Would someone kindly suggest a canonical application structure for this simple setup?

Thank you in advance,
MP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an NSMutableArray and store NSStrings in it. NSMutableArray supports inserting, adding, removing, reordering objects. You then look at the "Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections" of the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451), implement the right methods and update your NSMutableArray based model accordingly.

Comment: Thank you jbat!! Who should own that mutable array, the app delegate?

Comment: Typically it would be the view controller which owns the table view or some kind of central data management class (often singleton). Try to keep the app delegate doing its job (implementing the UIApplicationDelegate protocol).